# Owncloud Not Accessible by Ip on Local Network

Tags: web-server, hard-drive, mount, reset, owncloud

Okay, its so late its early now, so Stack Exchange is my only hope for solving this. I followed the instructions listed on this blog post at [pimylifeup.com](http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-owncloud/) to create an Owncloud webserver for myself. I am using a Raspberry Pi 2B with an external hard drive which has its own power source. When I try to access my Owncloud login page, I get an "unable to connect" message from firefox;

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at {IP Address}.

I could access the Owncloud login page perfectly with My Mac over wifi until I did two things:

1. I moved the directory to which the hard drive was mounted from `/media/usbstorage` to `/var`. I did this thinking that if I were using the pi as a web-server anyhow, I might as well as sock all the storage where all my web files will be.
2. I rebooted because I don't know.

If it is the mounting problem, what do I do? I need most of that storage in the public directory. Would it be easier to somehow move the owncloud installation to the /media folder?

Anyhow, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You say that you got "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at {IP Address}."  so what are you using to run the Firefox on - a Windows (or even better a Linux) PC?  If you followed the link you gave you presumably have an underlying Raspberry Pi distribution of something like Raspbian.  That being the case you ought to be able to log into the RPi with SSH and the default `pi` username and whatever password is used (by default it is `raspberry` but if you are setting up a Publicly accessible server *that needs to be changed as a minimum*!

Comment: Fortunately that same link also has [this link](http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-ssh/) explaining there how to log into the RPi over SSH, if that is not clear enough there must be literally *several* here on how to do it. 8-P

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I do know how to use ssh. What I'm having trouble with is why mounting my drive in the /var folder makes owncloud suddenly inaccessible.

Comment: Could there be a permissions issue - what are they for the directories where you moved the mount from and to - remember that a non-root user needs the e"**x**"ecute permission bit to be set on a directory in order to read the *contents* of that directory and a few parts of the `/var` parts of the file-system are restricted to the `root` user (or other privileged groups typically such as `adm` or `staff`).